# Subsonic 3, MySQL T4 template: Structs.tt fails

Tags: mysql, subsonic, subsonic3

Can anyone help?  When I try to generate my Structs.cs file, the process is failing with the error, becuase the SchemaName is not being returned by MySQL provider.

"
Error   3   Running transformation: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: objectToConvert
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(Object objectToConvert)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating3BD02BC645E0D86C85EB7201F039F235.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()....."

This is the code being generated in Structs.cs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Table: _companies
    /// Primary Key: ID
    /// </summary>

    public class _companiesTable: DatabaseTable {

        public _companiesTable(IDataProvider provider):base("_companies",provider){
            ClassName = "_company";
            SchemaName = "
```

I have tried using MySQL connector 6.04 and 5.1, and mysql server versions 5.067 and 5.1.33 with the same results.

This is the schema of the companies table:

-- Table "companies" DDL

CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you enter this as an issue please 
http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/issues